# Show that $\lim_{x \to b}\phi(x)=b$ for every $b \in \partial B$.

Tags: real-analysis

Let $h:B \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ the homeomorphism between the open ball with radio 1 and center by origin in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $\mathbb{R}^n$, given that $h(x)=\frac{x}{1-|x|}$. Let $a \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and $T:B \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ such that $T(x)=x+a$ and $\phi=h^{-1} \circ T \circ h$.\

Show that $\lim_{x \to b}\phi(x)=b$ for every $b \in \partial B$.

Let $x_k \in B$ such that $\lim x_k=b$, then

\begin{eqnarray*}
  \phi(x_k)=h^{-1}\left(\frac{x_k}{1-|x_k|}+a \right)&=&\frac{\left(\frac{x_k}{1-|x_k|}+a \right)}{1+\left| \frac{x_k}{1-|x_k|}+a \right| }\\
  &=&\frac{x_k+a-|x_k|a}{1+|x_k+a-a|x_k||} 
 \end{eqnarray*}

and
$1+|x_k+a-a|x_k|| \geq |x_k|+1-|a|\left( 1-|x_k|\right)\geq \frac{1}{2}$ for $k$ big enough.

then
\begin{eqnarray*}
  |\phi(x_k)-b|&=&\left| \frac{x_k+a-|x_k|a-b(1+|x_k+a-a|x_k||)}{1+|x_k+a-a|x_k||}\right| \\
  &\leqslant&2\left|x_k+a-|x_k|a-b(1+|x_k+a-a|x_k|| \right|\\
  &\leqslant&2|x_k-b|+ 2|a|(1-|x_k|)+2|x_k+a-a|x_k||
 \end{eqnarray*}

The first two terms tends to $0$, but  i dont know that do with the trird term.

Comment: It is not a good idea to attempt an $\epsilon - n_0$ argument unless specifically asked to do so. In this case the proof is quiet easy if you use basic theorems on limits (like limit of  a ratio is the ratio of the limits when the denominator does not vanish, etc).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just take limit for each term in the expression for $\phi(x_k)$:

$\phi(x_k)=\frac {x_k+a-a|x_k|} {1-|x_k|+|x_k+a-a|x_k||} \to \frac {b+a-a} {1-1+|b+a-a|}=\frac b {1}=b$.

Comment: is $1 \in \mathbb{R}^n?$

Comment: @CarlosAndresHenaoAcevedo Answer edited.